# jQuery Mobile is removing my nav bar

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile for it's multi-slider input binding (i.e. allowing inputs from both a type number and a type range). But on the site I'm installing this on, it's completely removing the navigation bar (https://www.autapse.com/managed-service-calculator/).

I have already broken jquery-mobile.css into only vital components and disabled the AJAX to prevent past site-breaking attributes, but this error is new.

Here's my initialization file:

```
<!-- Initializing Javascript -->

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  $.extend(  $.mobile , {
    ajaxEnabled: false,
    linkBindingEnabled: false,
    loadingMessage: false
  });
});
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Also, the loading message still displays at the bottom, even after turning the attribute to false.

If this approach is outdated and you have a better solution for binding the input number and input range, I would be extremely thankful for that as well!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't 'solve' it but wrote a viable alternative:

```
    <form>

        <h2>End User Desktop Support</h2>

        <label>Number of End Users:</label><br>
        <input class="add-quote" type="number" name="amountInput1" id="slider-1" min="0" max="1000" value="0" step="20" oninput="this.form.amountRange1.value=this.value">
          <input class="add-quote" type="range" name="amountRange1" min="0" max="1000" value="0" step="20" oninput="this.form.amountInput1.value=this.value" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1489255729054_225">

        <br>

        <label>Number of Internal Applications:</label><br>
        <input class="add-quote" type="number" name="amountInput2" id="slider-2" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="1" oninput="this.form.amountRange2.value=this.value">
          <input class="add-quote" type="range" name="amountRange2" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="1" oninput="this.form.amountInput2.value=this.value">

        <br>

        <label>Number of External Integrated Applications:</label><br>
        <input class="add-quote" type="number" name="amountInput3" id="slider-3" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="1" oninput="this.form.amountRange3.value=this.value">
          <input class="add-quote" type="range" name="amountRange3" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="1" oninput="this.form.amountInput3.value=this.value">

        <h2>Infrastructure Support</h2>

        <label>Number of Servers:</label><br>
        <input class="add-quote" type="number" name="amountInput4" id="slider-4" min="0" max="200" value="0" step="10" oninput="this.form.amountRange4.value=this.value">
          <input class="add-quote" type="range" name="amountRange4" min="0" max="200" value="0" step="1" oninput="this.form.amountInput4.value=this.value">

        <br>

        <label>Number of Network Circuits:</label><br>
        <input class="add-quote" type="number" name="amountInput5" id="slider-5" min="0" max="20" value="0" step="1" oninput="this.form.amountRange5.value=this.value">
          <input class="add-quote" type="range" name="amountRange5" min="0" max="20" value="0" step="1" oninput="this.form.amountInput5.value=this.value">

     </form>
```